# Adding new page to reactjs template

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently learning reactjs in order to create a small application
So I downloaded [this template](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react) from github and starting exploring it to understand how reactjs works.

And later I wanted to create a login page under the same template
So this what I did :
Under views I created new page Login.jsx inside Login folder
*path: views/Login/Login.jsx*

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "material-ui";

import {
  ItemGrid
} from "components";

function Login({ ...props }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container>
        <ItemGrid xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
          test loginpage
        </ItemGrid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

and then I imported it in app.jsx and i created a new route under appRoutes

*path: routes/app.jsx*

```
const appRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    component: LoginPage,
  },
 ....
]
```

and then I made this change to the main container App.jsx:
*path: containers/App/App.jsx*
I created a method getLogin

```
getLogin() {
  return this.props.location.pathname !== "/login";
}
```

and I changed

```
<Sidebar
    routes={appRoutes}
  logoText={"RecBot Cpanel"}
  logo={logo}
  image={image}
  handleDrawerToggle={this.handleDrawerToggle}
  open={this.state.mobileOpen}
  color="blue"
  {...rest}
/>
```

into this

```
{this.getLogin() ? (
  <Sidebar
    routes={appRoutes}
    logoText={"RecBot Cpanel"}
    logo={logo}
    image={image}
    handleDrawerToggle={this.handleDrawerToggle}
    open={this.state.mobileOpen}
    color="blue"
    {...rest}
  />

) : (
    <div></div>
  )}
```

in order to hide the sidebar from displaying in the login page.

and finally when I tried to run the app the login page works fine but in any other routes I got this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Sidebar`.

Here's the sidebar component:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import cx from "classnames";
import {
  withStyles,
  Drawer,
  Hidden,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText
} from "material-ui";

import { HeaderLinks } from "components";

import sidebarStyle from "variables/styles/sidebarStyle.jsx";

const Sidebar = ({ ...props }) => {
  // verifies if routeName is the one active (in browser input)
  function activeRoute(routeName) {
    return props.location.pathname.indexOf(routeName) > -1 ? true : false;
  }
  const { classes, color, logo, image, logoText, routes } = props;
  var links = (
    <List className={classes.list}>
      {routes.map((prop, key) => {
        if (prop.redirect) return null;
        const listItemClasses = cx({
          [" " + classes[color]]: activeRoute(prop.path)
        });
        const whiteFontClasses = cx({
          [" " + classes.whiteFont]: activeRoute(prop.path)
        });
        return (
          <NavLink
            to={prop.path}
            className={classes.item}
            activeClassName="active"
            key={key}
          >
            <ListItem button className={classes.itemLink + listItemClasses}>
              <ListItemIcon className={classes.itemIcon + whiteFontClasses}>
                <prop.icon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText
                primary={prop.sidebarName}
                className={classes.itemText + whiteFontClasses}
                disableTypography={true}
              />
            </ListItem>
          </NavLink>
        );
      })}
    </List>
  );
  var brand = (
    <div className={classes.logo}>
      <a href="https://www.creative-tim.com" className={classes.logoLink}>
        <div className={classes.logoImage}>
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" className={classes.img} />
        </div>
        {logoText}
      </a>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <Hidden mdUp>
        <Drawer
          variant="temporary"
          anchor="right"
          open={props.open}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
          onClose={props.handleDrawerToggle}
          ModalProps={{
            keepMounted: true // Better open performance on mobile.
          }}
        >
          {brand}
          <div className={classes.sidebarWrapper}>
            <HeaderLinks />
            {links}
          </div>
          {image !== undefined ? (
            <div
              className={classes.background}
              style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + image + ")" }}
            />
          ) : null}
        </Drawer>
      </Hidden>
      <Hidden smDown>
        <Drawer
          anchor="left"
          variant="permanent"
          open
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
        >
          {brand}
          <div className={classes.sidebarWrapper}>{links}</div>
          {image !== undefined ? (
            <div
              className={classes.background}
              style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + image + ")" }}
            />
          ) : null}
        </Drawer>
      </Hidden>
    </div>
  );
};

Sidebar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(sidebarStyle)(Sidebar);
```

what did i do wrong ?

Comment: please share `Sidebar` render method, the problem seems to be there

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas done

Comment: `import { HeaderLinks } from "components"` do you have **components** as webpack alias?

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas yes ofc , the template was woking fine at first

Comment: yeah I was seeing that. Another thing, do you have an `icon` property insite your route array objects? if not remove `<prop.icon />` and see what happen.

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas yes that did remove the error ! but it remove the icon for the other elements is there any possible way to keep icon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to check if the `icon` is present in you `prop` object

```
{prop.icon && <prop.icon />}
```

in this way you'll keep your icons if they exist and avoid the error if they don't.

You can see this [page](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) to learn more about conditional rendering in react.

Comment: perfect ! thanks . just i needed to warp the whole `ListItemIcon` since i got **TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**